# How to link your facebook feed dialog news feed to your app in itunes app store? - iphone

Tags: iphone, facebook, dialog, feed, itunes-store

I am using the facebook feed dialogs as mentioned here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

to post a newsfeed on the users wall. There are 2 problems though:
The link to my app is not coming up, so It says via Cool Social App , but without any hyperlinks. 
How do I make it show the hyper link?
Secondly, I would like the hyperlink to navigate to my itunes app store link where all the information about the iOS app is available, and the user can download if interested. 
Is it possible to do the above? Thanks in advance for any help!!!!

Answer (score 2):

While setting the params for the feed dialog, make sure you include the following.

```
[params setValue: @"url_link_to_app_store" forKey: @"link"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by giving app url, canvas url etc in the facebook app settings. This redirects the users to the url which is a custom website, where I gave the info about the app and the itunes link. Hope that helps anybody who wants to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

To have it load your app in the iTunes store, you need to fill out the sections called "native iOS app" in the Facebook app configuration page.